# Error in Heroku with Flask App and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, heroku, sqlalchemy

I have an app written in Python using Flask that I'm deploying using Heroku. I'm running into an issue after the built, the console gives me numerous lines of error but the main one being, to me:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Binary' from 'sqlalchemy' (/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/__init__.py)
```

The related file begins with:

```py
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy import Binary, Column, Integer, String
from app import db, login_manager
```

My requirement.txt file is a follow:

```
flask
sqlalchemy
flask_login
flask_migrate
flask_wtf
flask-sqlalchemy
email_validator
python-decouple
gunicorn
fiona
pyproj
rtree
shapely
geopandas
plotly
matplotlib
tqdm
```

I fail to understand the origin mainly particulalry considering that:

- the app run fine on my computer (however it runs in a conda env, not pip)
- the app was fine a few days ago, nothing related to SQL has changed since

Does someone know where it could be coming from?

Thank you!

Comment: What version of sqlalchemy are you installing on your computer versus what version of sqlalchemy is being installed by Heroku? Your requirements file does not specify any particular version so it is possible you and Heroku are using different versions of sqlalchemy and in your version you can import Binary from sqlalchemy but in another version it may be elsewhere.

Comment: I'm using 2.5.1 so I added sqlalchemy>=2.5 to my requirement files. But why wouldn't Heroku through pip install the last version? But when trying again with that config it still doesn't work...

Comment: I think SQLAlchemy's latest version is 1.4.8, I would check again on the versioning. It is always good to pin to an exact version to avoid pip (or conda) installing things that have breaking changes between versions. An example of a breaking change may be relocating the Binary type within the module itself. Try figuring out what version runs locally and use sqlalchemy==1.4.8 or whatever it is. (current sqlalchemy version source: https://www.sqlalchemy.org/download.html#current)

Comment: Yes, sorry I looked at flask-sqlalchemy. sqlalchemy is 1.3.23 and specifying the version worked well! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

For posterity, I solved it by being more precise in my requirement files as follow:

```
flask
sqlalchemy==1.3.23
flask_login
flask_migrate
flask_wtf
flask-sqlalchemy>=2.5
email_validator
python-decouple
gunicorn
fiona
pyproj
rtree
shapely
geopandas
plotly
matplotlib
tqdm
```